# Sort by Reflection faster then by Member?

Tags: c#, performance, list, sorting, reflection

There are a lot of warnings regarding the speed of using Reflection in .Net.
For sorting a datagridview by column Datapropertyname I made a short test program which shows Linq Sort by Reflection is faster then by Member.
I am not sure if I all have done correctly and ask the community for a review.

```
class Program {

    private static Random random = new Random();

    class TestClass {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }


     static string RandomString(int length) {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }


    static void SortyByReflection(List<TestClass> testlst) {
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Name").FirstOrDefault();
        List<TestClass> sorted = testlst.OrderBy(o => prop.GetValue(o)).ToList();
    }

    static void SortByMember(List<TestClass> testlst) {
        List<TestClass> sorted = testlst.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
    }


    delegate void dRunner(List<TestClass> testlst);

    static long UsedTime(dRunner testDelegate, List<TestClass> testlst) {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        testDelegate(testlst);
        timer.Stop();
        return timer.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // make a dry run to init the program
        SortByMember(new List<TestClass>());
        SortyByReflection(new List<TestClass>());


        List<int> lstSize = new List<int> { 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 };
        foreach (int count in lstSize) {
            // Init List
            List<TestClass> testlst = new List<TestClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                testlst.Add(new TestClass { Name = RandomString(10), Number = i });
            }
            List<long> reflection = new List<long>();
            List<long> memberTime = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                reflection.Add(UsedTime(SortyByReflection,testlst));
                memberTime.Add(UsedTime(SortByMember,testlst));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{reflection.Min()} / {reflection.Max()} / {reflection.Average()} Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection {count} size");
            Console.WriteLine($"{memberTime.Min()} / {memberTime.Max()} / {memberTime.Average()} Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member {count} size");
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    /*
     * Sample output
        425 / 1837 / 539,75 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100 size
        479 / 1265 / 605,14 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        6251 / 11819 / 7309,82 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 1000 size
        7164 / 13369 / 8201,42 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 1000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        76214 / 103169 / 82003,53 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 10000 size
        86139 / 121152 / 93201,55 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 10000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1092454 / 1188244 / 1139228,26 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100000 size
        1225469 / 1353753 / 1280549,37 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        done
    */
}
```

The Average is always around 10% faster when using Reflection.

After implementing it new (Release, Run outside of Visual Studio, Consuming the Result and **changing vom Order  by Name to Order by Number** the world is in balance again.

The new numbers where as espected:

```
/*
97 / 1266 / 129,67 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100 size
19 / 265 / 28,34 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100 size
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1064 / 2369 / 1357,42 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 1000 size
218 / 598 / 290,43 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 1000 size
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
12407 / 27326 / 15779,35 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 10000 size
2703 / 5100 / 3366,52 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 10000 size
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
147184 / 198677 / 160490,02 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100000 size
35333 / 45620 / 38493,46 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100000 size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

And for the files, here is the new source code

```
  class Program {

    private static Random random = new Random();

    class TestClass {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }


     static string RandomString(int length) {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }


    static List<TestClass> SortyByReflection(List<TestClass> testlst) {
        PropertyInfo prop = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Number").FirstOrDefault();
        List<TestClass> sorted = testlst.OrderBy(o => prop.GetValue(o)).ToList();
        return sorted;
    }

    static  List<TestClass> SortByMember(List<TestClass> testlst) {
        List<TestClass> sorted = testlst.OrderBy(o => o.Number).ToList();
        return sorted;
    }


    delegate List<TestClass> dRunner(List<TestClass> testlst);

    static List<TestClass> UsedTime(dRunner testDelegate, List<TestClass> testlst,out long time) {
        time = 0;
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        var x = testDelegate(testlst);
        timer.Stop();
        time = timer.ElapsedTicks;
        return x;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {


        // make a dry run to init the program
        SortByMember(new List<TestClass>());
        SortyByReflection(new List<TestClass>());


        List<int> lstSize = new List<int> { 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 };
        foreach (int count in lstSize) {
            // Init List
            List<TestClass> testlst = new List<TestClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                testlst.Add(new TestClass { Name = RandomString(10), Number = i });
            }
            List<long> reflection = new List<long>();
            List<long> memberTime = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                foreach (var lst in UsedTime(SortyByReflection,testlst,out long time)){
                    var tmp = lst.Name;
                    tmp += lst.Number.ToString();
                    reflection.Add(time);
                }
                foreach (var lst in UsedTime(SortByMember, testlst, out long time)) {
                    var tmp = lst.Name;
                    tmp += lst.Number.ToString();
                    memberTime.Add(time);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{reflection.Min()} / {reflection.Max()} / {reflection.Average()} Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection {count} size");
            Console.WriteLine($"{memberTime.Min()} / {memberTime.Max()} / {memberTime.Average()} Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member {count} size");
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    /*
        97 / 1266 / 129,67 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100 size
        19 / 265 / 28,34 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1064 / 2369 / 1357,42 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 1000 size
        218 / 598 / 290,43 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 1000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        12407 / 27326 / 15779,35 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 10000 size
        2703 / 5100 / 3366,52 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 10000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        147184 / 198677 / 160490,02 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 100000 size
        35333 / 45620 / 38493,46 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 100000 size
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
}
```

Comment: Are you running a release build (not a debug build) and doing so outside of visual studio (no debugger attached)?

Comment: For the above numbers : No. But here are the numbers for Release / outside Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry, to slow, Had trouble with formatting.    As Example   55147 / 68283 / 59714,92 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Reflection 10000 size    
65467 / 77350 / 70023,09 Min/ Max / Average Ticks needed for Member 10000 size

Comment: Update your question, not in the comments. Benchmarking should always be done in release build outside of VS. Also it's possible your results are skewed. You aren't returning (or using) the sorted list so for all I know the compiler recognizes this and is performing some optimizations to Elide the method call. Return the sorted list, store it in another list in UsedTime. In UsedTime, log the returned list's count property (which will be the same, but will ensure its not getting removed optimized away). Also try calling member/reflection in the opposite order. Benchmarking is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time I saw the post, I didn't trust it like other commenters.

But after doing my own tests eliminating the potential GC and JIT affects, I can confirm that the claims are correct - the `SortyByReflection` method is indeed faster in average than the `SortByMember`.

However, this has nothing to do with reflection!

After all, the `Enumerable.OrderBy` method does **O(N)** selector invocations (i.e. reflection vs direct property access you are trying to measure) and average **O(N * Log2(N))** *comparisons*, hence the time complexity is dominated by the comparison operation implementation.

And here comes the difference. The reflection method is using `Comparer<object>.Default` while the other method is using `Comparer<string>.Default`. And surprisingly for some unknown reason the former is faster than the later for `string`s. I haven't tested for other data types (most likely for `int` and other value types the picture will be the opposite due to the boxing involved in the first case), but this is the case for `string`. I've checked the reference source for the comparer implementations and have some ideas what could be causing it, but that falls outside the scope of the current question.

The important thing is that `OrderBy` is not good for testing the reflection vs direct access performance. If you change the first method selector to `o => (string)prop.GetValue(o)` and keep the second as is, or change the second selector to `o => (object)o.Name` and keep the first as is, running the test will show you that direct access is faster than the reflection as expected, but not so much due to the comparison time domination, especially for bigger `N`.

Comment: Just to add to this, `List<T>.Sort` performs significantly better than `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy`, and the slow part of the reflection (`GetProperties` etc) is executed once before the `OrderBy` loop. Reflection is also much less safe to use as the type being reflected may change in the future, and you may skip guard conditions, and this is the biggest reason not to use reflection IMHO. `Comparer<object>` may be faster than `string` because it's not using cultures to compare etc. It may not even be giving the same result, as the correctness is never checked.